# Windows Phone: Visual C# - Changing background picture and and button click new page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

**Question 1:**
How do I change the background of my application home (Custom Picture)?

**Question 2**
How do I code it to where I press a button and it opens a new page like the default emulator screen?

Ex. Buttons with all People and you click one then it takes you to Buttons with just the info of that person.

Comment: Welcome in so.Its better to show what you try.Without your effort no one interested to help you.

Comment: I tried making a new xaml file and looked up for a way to switch to it on click of the button.

Answer (score 1):

1) Add this child element to the LayoutRoot:

```
    <Grid.Background>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Background.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center" />
    </Grid.Background>
```

2) Use NavigationService:

```
    private void ButtonGoToOtherPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/OtherPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

You can pass GET parameters to the Uri: /OtherPage.xaml?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2

And then get them on the destination page:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(Microsoft.Phone.Navigation.PhoneNavigationEventArgs e) 
    { 
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e); 
        String parameter1 = NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter1"]; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. About the background, I'm getting "The file 'Images/Background.jpeg' is not part of the project or its 'Build Action' properly is not set the 'Resource'". Sorry, I'm a beginner, I asked a lot of questions when I learned java.